# Issue with running JUnit test with @Test on Android. Expected annotation not working

Tags: android, junit, junit3

I use Eclipse and I added JUnit4 in libraries. A have test where I expect exceptions and I use `@Test` annotations with parameters like this:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void setNullClassLoader() {
    Noob.setClassLoader(null);
}
```

But this is not working. I don't get complete test, I get "test failed" with exception `NullPointerException`. This is example of my test result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal return count
at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:591)
at com.example.testlualib.tests.LuaStateErrorTest.testIllegalCall2(LuaStateErrorTest.java:256)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1873)
```

All my tests extends from [AndroidTestCase](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html), also I add `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` annotation for my main test class:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public abstract class AbstractLuaTest extends AndroidTestCase {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a JUnit 4 test (with the nice annotations) then you must not extend AndroidTestCase. Please remove the `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)`, too. This runner is deprecated. You should use the default runner which does not need an `@RunWith` annotation.

```
public abstract class AbstractLuaTest {
    ...
}
```